# Storing video duration time in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

What's the most appropriate type used to store the duration time information of a video in sql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [several options](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server), including using the builtin DateTime or Time data type with offset from a particular fixed zero (which will allow you to use the built-in date/time function to get hours, minutes and seconds, etc.

If you were on pre-SQL Server 2005, you could combine it with a [user-defined data type technique](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/12/02/2959.aspx) (if your spans are less than 24 hours) to constrain the date part to be guaranteed not to wander.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how granular you need and if you have any constraints on a maximum time.  For example, would you need to know down to the millisecond of time duration or is 1 second granular enough?  The other thing to consider is how much data do you (or can you) store.

For SQL Server 2005, you have these constraints:

tinyint

- min = 0
- max =255
- Size = 1 byte

smallint

- min = -2^15 (-32,768)
- max= 2^15 - 1 (32,767)
- Size = 2 bytes

int

- min = -2^31 (-2,147,483,648)
- max = 2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647)
- Size = 4 bytes

bigint

- min = -2^63
  (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808)
- Max = 2^63 - 1
  (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)
- Size = 8 bytes

Answer (score 2):

Just store it as a DateTime - you get sorting, formatting and calculations built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I would store it as an INT representing the number of seconds, but I suppose it all depends what you need to do with the information in your database (you wouldn't want to have to convert it to HH:MM:SS or something else in your DB)

Comment: yeah, i need to make this type of convertion. but it helps anyway because the convertion is trivial, thanks.